# Oracle OCI - fetch delays and fails

Tags: oracle, rdbms, oracle-call-interface

I've got an Oracle OCI program, which is in production on various platforms: SLES Linux, Ubuntu, AIX, Solaris and HP-UX.  I'm trying to get the same thing running on Redhat, and I'm having difficulties.

The problem seems to arise when using a scrollable cursor (calling `OCIStmtExecute` with `OCI_STMT_SCROLLABLE_READONLY`), and using a function that does a binary search to get the exact result set size.  More generically, the problem seems to be reading past the end of the result set, before reading an OK value.

I have written a test utility which executes a simple statement that must return 1 row (`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM xxx`).  It then retrieves data from the result set:

If I first retrieve row 1, it works fine.  If I then go past the end of the result set, it continues to work fine when I return.  But if my first check is after the result set, everything goes wrong:

```
> rdb_test 1
12:06:32.365 Checking row 1 - OK

> rdb_test 3
12:06:35.510 Checking row 3 - NO DATA
12:06:35.511 Checking row 2 - NO DATA
12:06:45.549 Checking row 1 - NO DATA

> rdb_test -3
12:06:49.344 Checking row 1 - OK
12:06:49.344 Checking row 3 - NO DATA
12:06:49.345 Checking row 2 - NO DATA
12:06:49.345 Checking row 1 - OK
```

Also there is a strange delay, 10s in the example above, while it retrieves the row which should be OK.  In the debugger, this is deep within the OCIStmtFetch2 function - unsurprisingly in the __read_nocancel function waiting for the server response.

Has anyone else seen this problem before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be related to the version 11 OCI library.  I have just tried the v10 library, and it seems to work OK again with that.  Unfortunately, that requires an old version of the C++ standard library, so I would still prefer to avoid this fix if an alternative is available.